# Как SELinux понимает и определяет сущности системы и возможные действия с ними (файлы, папки и т д)?

Tags: linux, selinux

В чем суть. В главном файле политики (`sepolicy`) и его исходнике `sepolicy.cil` необходимо явно описывать сущности ("классы") системы и действия с ними. Вот пример с файлом:

```
 ~ # cat /system/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy.cil
...
(class dir (add_name remove_name reparent search rmdir ))
...
```

Странно, что вообще приходится явно описывать классы и действия с ними, разве это не должно быть зашито в ядре Linux? Просто когда я загрузил Debian Live USB с параметром ядра `lsm=selinux` и глянул в `/sys/fs/selinux/class`, данная папка оказалась... пустой. Т е из этого следует, что классы и действия с ними необходимо описывать явно в политике. Вопрос: как вообще это работает? Не следует ли из этого, что можно описать свои сущности и действия с ними, и как их описать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса dir есть 25 разрешений. В файле политики описаны связи цепочки: пользователь - шаблоны - разрешения - объект. Создавать новые объекты можно, но не тут.

Comment: вопрос: а где и как тогда можно создавать новые объекты?

Comment: а из чего вы их создавать хотите?

Comment: помимо того что есть в `sepolicy.cil` можно создавать контексты, интерфейсы, шаблоны политик.